# How to rename dropdown from Grafana table query

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

I have a grafana **table panel** with two queries.
Dropdown from the second query is displaying the SQL column names as the title of the dropdown.
I have named it ~Historical Stats test~ to be the title of the dropdown but it seems to show column names as title.
Is there any fix/solution for this ?

Have attatched a photo of the behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After 30 Minutes I found lol....really simple.
At left, just at the top of word "metrics browser", you can click on the default name of query "A", just click on A and edit.

[edit query name in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1yed.png)

update:
very sorry, your issue is more complicaded. maybe you can accept merge the 2 query.

[image]

Comment: Please, [edit] your answer and add text description. [Why link-only answers not good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34099298)